# Why is innerHTML not giving me the element tags?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML document with the following:

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>lorem error ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem success ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum lorem</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum success</p>
        <p>error lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum lorem</p>
        <p>lorem ipsum error</p>
        <p>success lorem ipsum</p>
        <script src="sandbox.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my js file, I have this:

```js
const paras = document.querySelectorAll("p");
paras.forEach((para) => {
    console.log(para.innerHTML);
});
```

I want to get the inner contents with the `<p>` tags included.

However, I just get the inner contents. No `<p>` tags.
Can someone explain why?

Thank you!

Comment: Think about what "inner HTML" means: it's the **content** of the elements. You can use `.outerHTML` instead if you want the container tags in addition to the content.

Comment: @Pointy is absolutely right you can use para.outerHTML  to get  `<p>lorem ipsum error</p>` not just `lorem ipsum error`

Comment: @Pointy you are champ of Javascript Man.. ;)

Comment: @Pointy Thank you! It makes sense now. I also found this image that helped clarify it more: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5kFb.png -- you're right, I want the outerHTML, not the innerHTML.

Comment: and with this I also learned something new today, thanks